# SSIS: Using rows from Flat file source and pass them as parameter values to stored procedure

Tags: ssis

I have followed the steps mentioned in the below post but with no success.

[SSIS Execute a Stored Procedure with the parameters from .CSV file SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772514/ssis-execute-a-stored-procedure-with-the-parameters-from-csv-file-sql-server-200)

I cant seem to map the flat file output columns to my stored procedure parameters, where is this done?

Thanks Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be under Column Mappings on the OleDB Command task.

[image: Column Mappings]

Comment: Thanks, I spotted that just after i did the post duh!