# Passing parameters to the stored proc frOM csv source to populate data in the destinaton using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures, parameters, ssis

The task I have iS,  I have a source is the CSV which  needs to be populate populated in      the SQL SERVER destination. I have written  a stored proc which needs around 7    parameters.  This stroed procedure takes the parameters, and populates the data   in 5 different tables in the target.  These parameters are supposed to come from a CSV as a source. I want to do this Using SSIS and i am not sure how  map the CSV Columns as the parameters to the stored procedure in SSIS

I am planing to design my package this way

Control flow task :  Dataflow task, execute sql task

Dataflow task :  flat file source, and SQL SERVER destination.

Am i in the right direction, if so, I want to know what kind of properties and the mappings , are to be done at the SSIS level to get this task done.

here are the parameters in the procedure.'

```
@customerid  varchar(50),    
@Name varchar(200), 
@abbrev varchar(50),   
@status bit,   
@startdate  datetime,   
@enddate datetime,   
@prodName varchar(100),   
@prodNumber  varchar(100),   
@website varchar(100)   

Exec registration (11,'abc company', 'abc', 'active','1/12/2004', '1/14/2010', ''01-2343-AS ','2343'www.abccompany.com')
```

Any help is immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this post, it should give you pointers for what you're looking to do.

[SSIS: Using rows from Flat file source and pass them as parameter values to stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096490/ssis-using-rows-from-flat-file-source-and-pass-them-as-parameter-values-to-store)